# in SAS how do I get this %macro to evaluate the way I want it?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Greetings SAS experts,

I have a lot of statements that will vary that are structured like this:

```
if item = '0123' then e123 = data1; if item = '0541' then r541 = data2;
```

the variable item contains character values that are numbers.

I have a lot of lines like the above and I wanted to write a macro inside of a data step that allows me to do something like this

```
%macro ifcondition(newitem);
if item = '&newitem' then E&newitem = data1; 
if item = '&newitem' then R&newitem = data2;
%mend;

%ifcondition(0123);
```

So I would like the numerous variants of this...

```
%ifcondition(0123);
```

to evaluate to this:

```
if item = '0123' then E0123 = data1; if item = '0123' then R0123 = data2;
```

What is the easiest way I can modify this so that this works correctly?

Thanks!!

Comment: Replace single quotes with double quotes to have macro variables resolved.

Comment: One solution is to remove single quote from '&newitem'. Move this single quote to where you call the macro: %ifcondition('0123');

Answer (score 0):

simply use double quotes, this worked for me:

```
data want;
input item $ try $ try2 $;
datalines;
0100 abcd aa
0101 pipp bb
0102 plut cc
2000 gian dd
2001 luca ee
2002 tryu ff
3007 troy gg
3156 boss hh
;

%macro ifcondition(newitem);
if item = "&newitem" then E&newitem. = try; 
if item = "&newitem" then R&newitem. = try2;
%mend;

data want1;
set want;
%ifcondition(0101);
%ifcondition(3007);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution was simple but worked fine. I was also able to use it to evaluate the way I wanted it to.